# Can I use get on a key in a jinja template?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7, jinja2

I have a list of keys and I'm trying to get the object(s) in a Jinja2 template:

`{{item.cities[0].get().name}}
UndefinedError: 'google.appengine.api.datastore_types.Key object' has no attribute 'get'`

I thought one could use `get()` on a key even in a template but here I get the error. Is it true that it can't be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you're confused between NDB keys and db keys. The db.Key class (here shown as datastore_types.Key) does not have a get() method.  However the NDB Key class (which would be google.appengine.ext.ndb.key.Key) does.

Comment: Aha I tried with `Cities.get(mykey)` since it is a db key and then it works. Thank you for the answer.